# Migrating @Html.Label from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to ASP.NET Core 7.0.

After migration, I get now a compiler error with the following code:

```
@Html.Label("My Label", new { @class = "mt-4 mb-2" })
```

I am using a lot of `@Html.Label` in my code, it seems that there is a new parameter introduced for this helper in .NET Core:

```
IHtmlContent Label(string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes);
```

Seems there is no overload anymore which accepts only two parameters like in ASP.NET MVC 5 (labelText + htmlAttributes).

I suppose I have to update all of them with an "expression" parameter, or is there another solution?

Comment: Do you want HTML markup  like :  `<label class="mt-4 mb-2" asp-for="item_Value">My Label</label>` ?

Comment: This would be an option, yes, but doing this in 400+places is not so convenient. Maybe there is a faster solution

Comment: You already have to change 4000 places. ASP.NET Core is a *completely* different stack. Not only have those helpers gone, there's no HttpContext.Current any more, and the entire pipeline is completely different.

Comment: You're trying to attempt a 7 year jump in your application - ASP.NET Core 1 was released in 2016. I suggest using the [.NET Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to find out what can be changed automatically and what needs manual changes, then follow a careful migration strategy based on the linked migration guide. If you try to re-create the old tags you'll spend a lot of time and *still* remain in ASP.NET MVC 5, with no tooling support this time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The helper has NOT gone, just a new parameter was added. Probably adding the new parameter as string.empty would be enough to have a quick solution.

Comment: @PinteDani if you refer to [IHtmlHelper.Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.label?view=aspnetcore-7.0), that's *not* the same as MVC 5's [Label extensions method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and hasn't changed since 2016. Just because the name is the same doesn't mean the methods are related. *Did you try the migration assistant*? It's quite possible the assistant will be able to make these changes automatically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have not tried "migration assistant", but I am pretty far with migration, the migration issue described here is a minor one, I just wanted to know the fastest solution

Comment: It's not a minor one at all. You confused one method for a completely unrelated one. Have you tried running *any* migrated page? If you wait until you replace all calls and compile, you may find out that *nothing* works the way you assumed because the methods you used return completely unexpected things. In this case, the two unrelated methods return completely different results that are meant to be used by completely different renderers

Answer (score 2):

I will always recommend using Label Tag Helper. You can use that like the following.

```
<label asp-for="My Label"></label>
```

That is easiest part of doing that.

Comment: That's the only practical solution. ASP.NET Core is a completely different stack. Different tags is the *least* of the changes. The pipeline, controllers, views, styles, authentication are all different - never mind HttpContext.Current

Comment: Besides, replicating the old tags means the project will still be in the same state (if not worse) after a lot of work, but this time no Migration Assistant will be able to process it. Actually migrating will require a *lot* more work in the future

Comment: I think you meant <label class="mt-4 mb-2">My Label</label>

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create your own static extension method that will copy signature of old Label method

```
public static class HtmlExtensions 
{
    public static IHtmlContent Label(this IHtmlHelper helper, string expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        return helper.Label(expression, expression, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple solutions to fix this Problem, in this scenario the cleaner solution would be to use directly a label:

```
<label></label>
```

But as a quick fix, with minor code changes, I managed to pass string.empty("") as a parameter:

```
@Html.Label("", "My Label", new { @class = "mt-4 mb-2" })
```

This will render the label, but because of the empty first parameter, we get this **for** generated:

[image]

As a conclusion, I would use the `<label>` tag directly for new code in such cases, and `@Html.Label` should be used only if there is an expression to bind to.

Probably in ASP.NET Core that overload was removed for exactly this reason.

Comment: No, it wasn't removed- it's not even an overload. You're calling a completely different method on a completely different class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that asp.net core has a completely new infrastructure, I agree, that's clear. But a LOT of HTML helpers have exactly the same signatures for making migration easier, and some of them were changed/removed. That's what I wanted to mention

Answer (score -1):

> I suppose I have to update all of them with an "expression" parameter,
> or is there another solution?

Another solution : You can create HTML Helpers with Extension Methods like:

LabelExtensions:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
 {
     public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent Label(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
     {
         var str = String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", htmlAttributes, labelText);
         return new HtmlString(str);

     }
 }
```

After you create an extension method, and build your application successfully, the extension method appears in Visual Studio Intellisense like all of the other methods of a class .

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The Label helpers in both frameworks do a lot more than call `String.Format`. Besides, calling `String.Format` with an anonymous type argument would only print the type's internal name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  yes, you are correct, the Label helpers in both frameworks do a lot more than call String.Format.  At the first I comment,  suggest op to use `<label class="mt-4 mb-2" asp-for="item_Value">`, but he thinks doing this in 400+places is not so convenient, then I give op the option. Of course the `<label>`  is  better.